# Getting triangles side coords within a circle

Tags: java, geometry

I want to get the x and y coördinates on the triangle for every degree 'a', if I know the 30° and the radius. I also want to use it with more corners.

Here is the image:
https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/104060836/Image.png

Any help would appreciated.

I already tried this code:

```
/**
 * Gets the points on the shape around the location.
 * @param location
 * @param diameter
 * @param amount
 * @param degreesBetweenPoint
 * @return points
 */
public static List<Location> getShapeLinePoints(Location location, NecroPlane plane, double diameter, int amount, int degreesBetweenPoint) {
    List<Location> points = new ArrayList<Location>();

    double r = diameter / 2;

    int c1 = 180 / amount;
    int c2 = c1 / 2;

    for (int i = 0; i < (360 / degreesBetweenPoint); i++) {
        int d = i * degreesBetweenPoint;

        int d1 = d;
        while (d1 >= c1) {
            d1 -= c1;
        }

        int d2 = 180 - c2 - d1;

        double z = (r * Math.sin(Math.toRadians(c2))) / Math.sin(Math.toRadians(d2));
        double x = Math.sin(Math.toRadians(d)) * z;
        double y = Math.cos(Math.toRadians(d)) * z;

        switch (plane) {
            case XZ:
                points.add(new Location(location.getWorld(), location.getX() + x, location.getY(), location.getZ() + y));
                break;
            case YZ:
                points.add(new Location(location.getWorld(), location.getX(), location.getY() + y, location.getZ() + x));
                break;
            case XY:
            default:
                points.add(new Location(location.getWorld(), location.getX() + x, location.getY() + y, location.getZ()));
        }
    }

    return points;
}
```

I got it working, here is the solution if anyone needs it:
http://pastie.org/8022687

Comment: What code have you tried and where are you stuck?

Comment: That should be posted at http://math.stackexchange.com/, but I'm not sure they'll like to do your homework.

Comment: I added my code, but it was creating weird stuff. Something like this: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/104060836/Image3.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For quadrant I., it is easy:
Use this (ASA) rule to calculate length of "z":
http://www.mathsisfun.com/algebra/trig-solving-asa-triangles.html

Now you have z, take the triangle with sides x, y and z. You know angle a), you know the 90°angle, so you can calculate all three angles. Now using the same rule as above, you can calculate lengths of x and y, which would be your x and y coordinate.

So for quadrant IV., use similar rules.

Since your full triangle is equilateral, the intersection of the triangle with x is -r/2.
The length of any of the three sides is : (3r)/sqrt(3).

I'm not much of a mathematician, so I hope someone can help you from here with the II. and III. quadrant.